# Font tag hover not working on firefox, but works normal on chrome

Tags: html, css

For some reason the hover is not working in my font tag on firefox, it works normal on chrome, but doens't work in firefox. If i try to hover another tag (button and div for example) it just works as intended. I'm using firefox 64.0

Here's a example in codepen: https://codepen.io/luansergiomattos/pen/MZoMPX

```
<body>
    <div class="header__account">
        <button class="header__font">
            <font  class="header__font">LOGIN</font>
        </button>

        <button>
            <font class="header__font">REGISTER</font>
        </button>
    </div>
</body>
```

css

```
 .header__font:hover {
    animation: 0.5s ease-out 0s 1 forwards highlight;

  }

  .header__font::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2px;
    bottom: -7px;
    background: red;
    visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 5px;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: 0.25s linear;
  }

  .header__font:hover::before {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }

.header__font:focus::before {
    visibility: visible;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
```

Sorry if there is a lot of stuff in my code, i just copied from the project i'm working

How do i fix this?

Comment: Why are you using this [obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) and prehistoric tag? Did you check the [browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/font#Browser_compatibility)?

Comment: That's a 15 yo bug/odd behavior of FF. They don't bubble <button>'s inner element's mouse events but rather make it like they all started from the <button> directly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When hovering over a child element in firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41210684/when-hovering-over-a-child-element-in-firefox)

Comment: Ah yes yours is better thanks @ksav (even though FF exposes the same behavior with <span>...)

Comment: thanks for the comments

Answer (score 0):

According to [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_font.asp) the font tag is not supported by HTML5,
I suggest you have to change your code.

However, I find the following coding is working.

```
<div class="header__account">
    <button class="header__font">
        LOGIN
    </button>
    <button  class="header__font">
        REGISTER
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, but i needed to have another element inside the button to control de size

Answer (score 0):

This might help you...

```
div.header__font:hover {
    animation: 0.5s ease-out 0s  forwards highlight;
}
```

Comment: Have you applied it to all hover in your css ?